# The order b if $ab=b^2a$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is a group, $a$ is the element s.t. the order $ord(a)=3$, if $b$ satisfies $ab=b^2a$, what is $ord(b)$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- Show that $aba^{-1}=b^2$.
- Then show that $ab^ka^{-1}=b^{2k}$ for all $k$.
- Then apply that to    find a formula for writing $a^2b^ka^{-2}$ as a
  power of $b$.
- Then    apply that to find a formula for writing    $a^3b^ka^{-3}$ as
  a power of    $b$.
- Then make some deductions. Only    few    alternatives remain.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted and like Jyrki's answer. Just thought I'd share mine

First, notice

$$e = a^3 = (b^2ab^{-1})^3 \iff e = (ba)^3$$

So that

$$b^2a = ab \iff b^3a^2 = (ba)^2 = (ba)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1} \iff ab^3a^{-1}=b^{-1}$$

By assumption we also have

$$aba^{-1}=b^2 \iff ab^{3}a^{-1}=b^6$$

So $b^6=b^{-1} \iff b^7=1$ which means $ord(b)=1$ or $ord(b)=7$.